I am getting an ERROR while making a blockchain based P2P energy trading marketplace
I am getting this error while deploying the project through command(truffle migrate --network development)
Initial Migration Code:-
const YourContract = artifacts.require("./YourContract.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(YourContract);
};

Deploy Contracts Code:-
const Marketplace = artifacts.require("Marketplace");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Marketplace);
};

I am trying to create P2P energy trading marketplace using truffle and ganache
And I am getting this error
I am not getting any solution for this error
